# Localization of rings and integral closures

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I looking at localizations of rings and I have the following problem:

Let $R=k[x]$ be a polynomial ring ($k$ a field) and $R'=k[x^2])$ (note $R$ is integral over $R'$. Then if I look at the ideal $M=(x^2-1)$ it will be maximal in $R'$. Now $M$ is not prime in $R$ as $(x-1)(x+1)=(x^2-1)$.  Now a result in Atiyah-Macdonald on page 61 says that $R'_M$ is integral over $R_M$, but note that $(1+x)$ is not in $M$ so $f=1/(x+1) \in R_M$ but this can't happen as I can prove $f$ cant be integral over $R'_M$, so what am I missing or whats wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Yes I see it now, it was just my notation that was confusing me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The notation $R_M$ means the following. Since you are viewing $R$ as an $R'$-module, $R_M = R'_M \otimes_{R'} R_M$. In other words, $R_M = W^{-1} R$ where $W = R' \setminus M$ not $R \setminus M$. In your example the element $1+x \notin R'$.